# Matlab take more time when storage a temporary variable

Tags: matlab, loops, stored-procedures, temporary

When I run this example codes, I found it take more time on the 8 line. I don't why, and is there any tips let it faster??

The x and y value is not important, I just curious about the red line why take so much time, in the real codes, they are two complex expressions, why storage take so much time?

```
result = zeros(2, 1000);
x=0;y=0;
tic
for i =1:200
    for j =1:200
        for k =1:1000
            x=x+x/2+2*y; y=y+x*y/2;
            result(:, k) = [x;y];
        end
        sum(result); % or other operations, just for example
    end
end
toc
```

[image]

Comment: Trying to understand your code, I would have expected a `x=0;y=0;` prior to the line `for k =1:1000`. Could you check if your code actually does what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please check your code again. Now x and y are always 0.

Comment: the real x and y value is not important, I just curious about the red line why take so much time, in the real codes, they are two complex expressions, thank you.

Comment: @zongxian See revised answer below

Comment: It takes so much time because it’s executed 40 million times. It’s only 160 ns per execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit looping is generally going to be slow compared to vector operations. In this case you can do:

```
x=0;y=0;
tic
for i =1:200
    for j =1:200
      result=[x+(1:1000)*i; y+(1:1000)*j];
      x=x+1000*i;
      y=y+1000*j;
      sum(result); % or other operations, just for example
    end
end
toc
```

Edit: In your revised example, do explicit updating instead of vector construction and slice assignment:

```
result = zeros(2, 1000);
x=0;y=0;
tic
for i =1:200
    for j =1:200
        for k =1:1000
            x=x+x/2+2*y; y=y+x*y/2;
            result(1, k) = x;
            result(2, k) = y;
        end
        sum(result); % or other operations, just for example
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe I am not explain my question clearly it not simple plus, so I have changed part of my question codes.